# `binding.pry` vs `pry`

Tags: ruby, pry

What is the difference between calling `pry` and `binding.pry`? For example:

```
require 'pry'

class Bookshop
  def initialize(book)
    @books = []
    @hp = 'harry potter'
    lotr = 'lord of the rings'
    @books << @harry_potter
    @books << lord_of_the_rings
    @books << book
    binding.pry #OR pry
  end

  def print_all_books
    puts @books.join(', ')
  end
end

new_bookshop = Bookshop.new('the hobbit')
```

- `binding.pry` gives me access to instance variable `@hp`, local variables `lotr`, and instance method `print_all_books`.
- `pry` gives access to instance variables and methods, but throws a `NameError: undefined local variable` for `lotr`.

Both indicate the same context. what is going on here? Is there a case in which calling `pry` over `binding.pry` is desirable?

Comment: `binding` is a special object which is where local variables are stored. By patching `pry` on to the `binding` object, these local variables become available to the debugger REPL. Note there's yet another way to do it: `Pry.start(binding)`. The `pry` method is actually defined on `Object`: see [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pry/pry/Object) for more explanation

Comment: I am testing it out and `Pry.start(binding)`  is equivalent to `binding.pry`. `Pry.start(binding)` seems more self-explanatory. Thanks! I am still not sure what calling `pry` alone does though.

Comment: `pry` method is defined on Object so you can call it on anything: `1.pry` for example, though there's no reason to do this. When you call it on `binding`, that makes the local variables available.

Comment: Unless this is a duplicate, you should make your comment an answer, @maxpleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-iterating what I said in comments.

If you look at the source for the method (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/pry/pry/Object), it is patched on Object which means you can call it on basically anything. Whatever you call it on becomes the value of `self` in the ensuing REPL. `pry`, `self.pry`, and `Pry.start(self)` all do the same thing.

`binding` is kind of a magic/complicated thing which captures the 'context' at a certain place, and makes those local variables accessible from elsewhere. By using `binding.pry` or `Pry.start(binding)` you ensure the local variables are in scope for the REPL (how, exactly, I can't say).

You also see `binding` used in other places where you want to reference local variables in some other scope. For example to evaluate a string of ERB you can use `ERB.new(string).result(binding)`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. This [article](http://kyrylo.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/05/29/so-what-is-binding-pry-exactly#top-level-footnote) also contains some good info and examples on the subject.